# cannot find -lcuda when linking with g++

Tags: c, gcc, cuda, linker, g++

I'm trying to link these object files with the command:

```
g++ NT_FFT_Decomp.o T_FFT_Decomp.o SNT_FFT_Comp.o ST_FFT_Comp.o VNT_FFT_Comp.o VT_FFT_Comp.o CUDA_FFT_Comp.o Globals.o main.o \
-L/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/include -lcuda -lcudart -lpthread -o DevicesTest
```

> /media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA

is my cuda installation directory.
and my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is like this :

```
Irrelevant:/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib64:/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib:Irrelevant
```

the command gives this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
```

removing -lcuda and -lcudart generates undefined reference to cuda functions errors.

how can I link this properly ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the compiler switch:

```
-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

or something similar, to tell g++ where to find the `-lcuda` and `-lcudart` libraries.

In your case, the line is probably:

```
-L/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib64
```

instead of the existing statement that you have.  (change `include` to `lib64` or possibly `lib`)

Again, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has nothing to do with compiling and linking.

Answer (score 2):

`-L/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/include // WRONG`: "-L" is for libraries ... but "/include" is usually for headers

SUGGESTED CHANGE: `-L/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib64`

COMPLETE LINK LINE:

```
g++ NT_FFT_Decomp.o \
  T_FFT_Decomp.o  \
  SNT_FFT_Comp.o  \
  ST_FFT_Comp.o  \
  VNT_FFT_Comp.o  \
  VT_FFT_Comp.o \
  CUDA_FFT_Comp.o \ 
  Globals.o main.o \
  -L/media/wiso/Programs/Setups/CUDA/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lpthread \
  -o DevicesTest
```